# Produção em horas PHP

Tags: php, lógica

Fala pessoal, to desenvolvendo uma página, e chegou na hora que eu particularmente não entendo muito, calculo de horas no php, seguinte: Tenho valores que vem do banco de dados, que são:

- Tempo do turno (08:00:00)(h:m:s) (valor varia de acordo com o turno)
- Pares por hora (15 pares por hora) (valor varia de acordo com a maquina)
- Produção, que vem de um input

quero realizar essa conta, pares por hora * tempo de turno, que me da o total de produção de 100%, depois só faço uma regra de 3 para saber a eficiência do turno;

alguém me sugere algo?

Comment: Cola uma parte do código que você já tem ai! Ai facilita da gente te ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui com a seguinte gambiarra:

```
    $horario: '08:20:00';
    $pares_p_hora : !valor vindo do BD;
    $producao = !valor vindo do BD;



    $segundos = strtotime('1970-01-01 '.$horario.'UTC');
    $tempo_producao = ($pares_p_hora / 3600);
    $tempo_producao = number_format(($tempo_producao * $segundos), 0, ',', '.');
    $eficiencia = number_format((($producao * 100) / $tempo_producao), 0, ',', '.');
    echo "eficiencia: ".$eficiencia."%<br>";
```